# Turning a string character into an int

Tags: c, string

Basically, I have this really long string full of digits:

```
char *number = "insert really long number";
```

Now I want to perform math operations on individual digits contained in this string, let's say the following (summing two consecutive digits in this string aka array of chars):

```
sum = number[i] + number[i+1];
```

However, this does not produce the correct result, it returns a garbage value. I know how to extract a single value with printf for example:

```
printf("%c", number[i]);
```

But how can I get this %c to use in computations as above? I tried with `atoi`, but I get "error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &".

Comment: Have you tried using strtol?

Comment: <any number of type char> - '0' will give you the number in integer type.

Comment: So you _actually_ have rather something like this: `char *number = "4544551144455444551";`? Please confirm.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Correct.

Comment: And please confirm also that the result you want for `char *number = "123";` is `6`

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Also correct.

Comment: It is worth mention that the solutions posted below work because the Standard _specifies_ that the digits `0, 1,... , 9` be encoded in a contiguous sequence; but, the Standard does _not_ specify ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) `atoi` accept string rather than single character

2) If you want to convert just one ACSII char 0 - 9 just use following code:

```
if(rChar >= '0' && rChar <= '9')
    val = rChar - '0';
```

Comment: This works for any character set and encoding that complies with C standards; not just ASCII.

Comment: This code sets up a problem with data flow logic. `val` is indeterminate and presumably has no meaning before and after the `if` statement. In other words, whatever is done with `val` should be done in the true branch, and, so—with C99—`val` should be declared in the true branch.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
 char *number = "123";

 int n = 0;
 char c;
 for (int i = 0; c = number[i]; i++)
 {
   n += number[i] - '0';
 }

 printf("n = %d\n", n);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Although I did manage to figure this out from the previous answers. But thanks!

Comment: How this kind of condition: `c = number[i]` can stop the for loop? With the `\0`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes. The value of `c = number[i]` is `\0` (= 0) and therefore the for will stop as the end condition will be `0`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't practise C from a decade *(...x2)*

Answer (score 2):

For any number which is represented as a datatype char, you can subtract that number from '0' to get that number in integer type.

**For example:**

```
char a = '5';
int num = a - '0';
//num will store 5
```

**Why this works?**

Because if you check the ASCII value for '5', it is 53 and for '0' it is 48. So the difference is 5. This will work for converting any number in character form to integer.

The ASCII value for '0' is 48, for '1' it is 49 and so on. So the subtraction from '0' results in giving us the difference of ASCII values.

Here is a link to ASCII values: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` convert string (`const char*`) to `int`, if you give it a `char` it will not work. A solution to convert a `char` to an `int` is to use the ASCII table:

```
char c = '9'
int v = c - '0'; // v == 9
```